# pygame snake game creation automation not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pygame, artificial-intelligence

trying to create an snake ai but the automation is not working for that i am calculating next move of 
next trajectory of snake by initializing
for that  i Am Calculating the next move of the  snake  by initializing snake coordinates to plus minus  10 in every direction so whenever the snake hits the wall the difference become 0 or 640 according to my screen resolution 640*480

the full code is given below

```py
import pygame
import time
import random
import math

pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 102)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (213, 50, 80)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (50, 153, 213)

dis_width = 600
dis_height = 400

dis = pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width, dis_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

snake_block = 10
snake_speed = 15

font_style = pygame.font.SysFont("bahnschrift", 25)
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 35)


def Your_score(score):
    value = score_font.render("Your Score: " + str(score), True, yellow)
    dis.blit(value, [0, 0])



def our_snake(snake_block, snake_list):
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, black, [x[0], x[1], snake_block, snake_block])



def Leftmove():
    x1_change=-10
    y1_change=0
    x1+=x1_change
    y1+=y1_change
    return x1_change,y1_change

def Rightmove():
    x1_change=10
    y1_change=0
    x1+=x1_change
    y1+=y1_change
    return x1_change,y1_change

def Topmove():
    x1_change=0
    y1_change=-10
    x1+=x1_change
    y1+=y1_change
    return x1_change,y1_change

def Downmove():
    x1_change=0
    y1_change=10
    x1+=x1_change
    y1+=y1_change
    return x1_change,y1_change

def nextMove(snake_head,x1_change,y1_change):

    x1=snake_head[0]
    y1=snake_head[1]
    next_left=x1-10
    next_right=x1+10
    next_top=y1-10
    next_down=y1+10
    #print(next_left,next_right,next_top,next_down)

    if next_left<0:
        Rightmove()
    if next_right>= dis_width:
        Leftmove()
    if next_top<0:
        Dowsnmove()
    if next_down>=dis_height:
        Upmove()    
    return x1_change,y1_change





def message(msg, color):
    mesg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
    dis.blit(mesg, [dis_width / 6, dis_height / 3])


def GameBody():
    while game_close!=False:
        dis.fill(blue)
        message("You Lost! Press C-Play Again or Q-Quit", red)
        Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    game_close=False
                    game_over = True
                    return game_close,game_over
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    GameBody()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x1_change = -10
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x1_change = 10
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y1_change = -10
                    x1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y1_change = 10
                    x1_change = 0




        if x1 >= dis_width or x1 < 0 or y1 >= dis_height or y1 < 0:
            game_close = True
        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change
        return x1,y1

        dis.fill(blue)
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, green, [foodx, foody, snake_block, snake_block])
        snake_Head = []
        snake_Head.append(x1)
        snake_Head.append(y1)
        snake_List.append(snake_Head)
        #print(snake_Head)
        #print(snake_List)
        if len(snake_List) > Length_of_snake:
            del snake_List[0]

       # Snake Hits Its Own Body    
        """
        for x in snake_List[:-1]:
            if x == snake_Head:
                game_close = True

        """
        our_snake(snake_block, snake_List)
        x1_change, y1_change = nextMove(snake_Head, x1_change, y1_change)
        Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
        pygame.display.update()


        #calculating distance
        def Distance():
            x=snake_Head[0]
            y=snake_Head[1]
            dis_fleft=foodx-x
            dis_fright=foody-y
            dis_food=foodx-x+foody-y
            print(dis_fleft,dis_fright,dis_food)
        Distance()



        if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 1

        clock.tick(snake_speed)

game_over = False 
game_over = False
def gameLoop():

    x1 = dis_width / 2
    y1 = dis_height / 2

    x1_change = 0
    y1_change = 0

    snake_List = []
    Length_of_snake = 1

    foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
    foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0

    while game_over!=True:
        GameBody()      
    pygame.quit()
    quit()


gameLoop()
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this code will immediately 'game over'.

At the start of game body you should have

While game_close! = True :

Rather than

While game_close! = False :

Also this is Python so you could use

While not game_close :

Also game_over = False is there twice and one of those lines should be game_close =False

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import math

pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 102)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (213, 50, 80)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (50, 153, 213)

dis_width = 600
dis_height = 400

dis = pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width, dis_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

snake_block = 10
snake_speed = 15

font_style = pygame.font.SysFont("bahnschrift", 25)
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 35)


def Your_score(score):
    value = score_font.render("Your Score: " + str(score), True, yellow)
    dis.blit(value, [0, 0])



def our_snake(snake_block, snake_list):
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, black, [x[0], x[1], snake_block, snake_block])



def Leftmove():
    x1_change=-10
    y1_change=0
    x1+=x1_change
    y1+=y1_change
    return x1_change,y1_change

def Rightmove():
    x1_change=10
    y1_change=0
    x1+=x1_change
    y1+=y1_change
    return x1_change,y1_change

def Topmove():
    x1_change=0
    y1_change=-10
    x1+=x1_change
    y1+=y1_change
    return x1_change,y1_change

def Downmove():
    x1_change=0
    y1_change=10
    x1+=x1_change
    y1+=y1_change
    return x1_change,y1_change

def nextMove(snake_head,x1_change,y1_change):

    x1=snake_head[0]
    y1=snake_head[1]
    next_left=x1-10
    next_right=x1+10
    next_top=y1-10
    next_down=y1+10
    #print(next_left,next_right,next_top,next_down)

    if next_left<0:
        Rightmove()
    if next_right>= dis_width:
        Leftmove()
    if next_top<0:
        Dowsnmove()
    if next_down>=dis_height:
        Upmove()    
    return x1_change,y1_change





def message(msg, color):
    mesg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
    dis.blit(mesg, [dis_width / 6, dis_height / 3])


def GameBody():
    while not game_close:
        dis.fill(blue)
        message("You Lost! Press C-Play Again or Q-Quit", red)
        Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    game_close=False
                    game_over = True
                    return game_close,game_over
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    GameBody()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x1_change = -10
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x1_change = 10
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y1_change = -10
                    x1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y1_change = 10
                    x1_change = 0




        if x1 >= dis_width or x1 < 0 or y1 >= dis_height or y1 < 0:
            game_close = True
        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change
        return x1,y1

        dis.fill(blue)
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, green, [foodx, foody, snake_block, snake_block])
        snake_Head = []
        snake_Head.append(x1)
        snake_Head.append(y1)
        snake_List.append(snake_Head)
        #print(snake_Head)
        #print(snake_List)
        if len(snake_List) > Length_of_snake:
            del snake_List[0]

       # Snake Hits Its Own Body    
        """
        for x in snake_List[:-1]:
            if x == snake_Head:
                game_close = True

        """
        our_snake(snake_block, snake_List)
        x1_change, y1_change = nextMove(snake_Head, x1_change, y1_change)
        Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
        pygame.display.update()


        #calculating distance
        def Distance():
            x=snake_Head[0]
            y=snake_Head[1]
            dis_fleft=foodx-x
            dis_fright=foody-y
            dis_food=foodx-x+foody-y
            print(dis_fleft,dis_fright,dis_food)
        Distance()



        if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 1

        clock.tick(snake_speed)

game_over = False 
game_close = False
def gameLoop():

    x1 = dis_width / 2
    y1 = dis_height / 2

    x1_change = 0
    y1_change = 0

    snake_List = []
    Length_of_snake = 1

    foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
    foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0

    while game_over!=True:
        GameBody()      
    pygame.quit()
    quit()


gameLoop()
```